# Rails: iOS version detection on mobile Safari in Production environment

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4

**Edit:** On mobile Safari I want to test for iOS version, say iOS  8.

Given `request.user_agent` returns:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) ...

Do these methods look sufficient (**edit:** specifically, is the regex sound)?

```
def ios_device?
  !!request.user_agent.match(/iphone|ipad|ipod/i)
end

def ios_8?
  is_ios_device && !!request.user_agent.match(/OS 8_/)
end
```

Comment: Why would anyone want to test for iOS 3 in 2015?

Comment: @heading_to_tahiti Is your comment more relevant? The number 3 was hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

In general, probably not. This is tricky (or impossible) to do reliably.

Here are some issues people have run into using the conventional `useragent` Ruby gem:

https://github.com/josh/useragent/issues/95

https://github.com/josh/useragent/issues/84

https://github.com/josh/useragent/issues/96

However in the specific case of iOS 3, that version of iOS is more limited than newer versions in how different kinds of requests may send different user agents, so perhaps your solution is adequate.

Comment: I've set a specific context, none of those links seem to apply. Given the new context, can you think of any problems? (btw I'm not using a gem, rather the aliased `user_agent` method) Thanks